# How to see what js is run on action - profileing javascript

Tags: javascript, profiling

Im trying to work out how a site behaves with its javascript.

Ive looked at the linked and inline javascript files and ive also looked at the id attributes that link the html to them, but its all a bit of a mess, is there a way using firebug (or a similar tool) that can show a timeline of which javascript functions are being run on event..

ie. i click a button and it shows me that the function `openLightBox` was called from the lightbox.js file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for something like Visial events? (just bookmark it in firefox)

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2

To profile you can use Chrome dev tools profiler, you do have a timeline option as well with events.